# EventManager for Reactjs throws "addHandler is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to setup a UI with Reactjs, however I get an error saying that the `addHandler` and `removeHandler` **is not a function**.

The following code is in a file called `bridge.js`

```js
// Global variable for describe on events from react components
var EventManager = {
  events: {},

  addHandler: function(eventName, handler) {
    if (eventName in this.events) {
      this.events[eventName].push(handler);
    } else {
      this.events[eventName] = [handler];
    }
  },

  removeHandler: function(eventName, handler) {
    if (eventName in this.events) {
      var index = this.events[eventName].indexOf(handler);
      this.events[eventName].splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};

// Handle events from client
function trigger(eventName, args) {
  var handlers = EventManager.events[eventName];
  handlers.forEach(handler => handler(JSON.parse(args)));
}

module.exports = { trigger: trigger };
```

Here, I try to utilize the EventManager to listen for a `trigger` with eventName `updateCharacterInfo`, but it throws the exception.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EventManager from "../bridge";

class Leftbar extends Component {
  state = {
    status: "",
    firstname: "",
    {...}

  };

  componentDidMount() {
    EventManager.addHandler(
      "updateCharacterInfo",
      this.updateCharacterInfo.bind(this)
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    EventManager.removeHandler("updateCharacterInfo", this.updateCharacterInfo);
  }
```

Comment: You didn't export  EventManager

Comment: Even if I add `module.exports = { ExportManager: ExportManager` it doesn't work..

Comment: If you're doing a named export, make sure to do a named import as well: `import { EventManager } from "../bridge";`

Comment: That actually took the error away @NicholasTower. Thank you very much! Should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the info in your comment it looks like you're doing a named export, but then a default import. You'll need to use a named import to match the export, by wrapping the name in curly brackets:

```
import { EventManager } from "../bridge"
```

Answer (score 1):

first you should export and then importing your data

```
  export var EventManager = {
  events: {},
  addHandler: function(eventName, handler) {
    if (eventName in this.events) {
      this.events[eventName].push(handler);
    } else {
      this.events[eventName] = [handler];
    }
  },

  removeHandler: function(eventName, handler) {
    if (eventName in this.events) {
      var index = this.events[eventName].indexOf(handler);
      this.events[eventName].splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};

// Handle events from client
export function trigger(eventName, args) {
  var handlers = EventManager.events[eventName];
  handlers.forEach(handler => handler(JSON.parse(args)));
}
```

for importing in your component

```
import { EventManager, trigger } from "../bridge";
```